# My dog consistently wakes up about an hour before I do

Tags: dogs, training, urination

My two-year-old dog seems to only be able to hold her pee for about six hours, which is unfortunately less than the amount of sleep I need to get in a night. We'll potty her before we go to bed, but she'll still consistently wake up an hour or so before I do, no matter what time we go to bed. As in, I tried going to bed earlier and getting up earlier to take her out, but she only got up even earlier.

Now that she's been doing this for a little bit, she'll also start whining for her breakfast. I hate giving it to her because I know it's only training her to get up early and eat; but I also can't deal with her whining for a half hour while I'm trying to sleep.

How can we train her to be better at waiting for us to get up in the morning? For example, not giving her water after a certain time? I'm hesitant to try that on my own because I already worry we don't give her enough water.

Aside from this, she's otherwise house-trained pretty well. I don't think she's had a daytime accident for a few months now.

Comment: Is this a change or has it always been this way? How do you feel about trying to sleep 2 x 4 hour "shifts"? (It's much less awful than 6 hours. Because your sleep cycles are about 4 hours long.

Comment: @Sobrique Well, it took her a while to learn how to go outside, but she was doing okay for a few weeks between consistently going outside and whining to go out (so at least she knows she has to go out!), so I don't know if I can really say it's a change, we only brought her home in January and her training is still evolving.

Comment: @Sobrique Well, it would be better than 6 but I also don't know how much she'd like that and whether she'd actually go. I guess I'd rather start by giving her water more intelligently then maybe trying taking her out in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 5):

It seems I had misdiagnosed what was causing her to get up so early.

The culprit seems to have been the sunrise sneaking earlier and earlier. Bringing her into the much darker bedroom made her sleep in later. She'll even sleep through the alarm now.